# sql17 - The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 't'

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I write below query in mssm 17.

```
select t.id,
max (case when seq=1 then label end) as label-1,
max (case when seq=2 then label end) as label-2,
max (case when seq=3 then label end) as label-3,
max (case when seq=4 then label end) as label-4,
max (case when seq=5 then label end) as label-5,
from (select t1.*,t2.*,
row-number () over (partition by t1.id order by t2.label) as seq
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.sequence
) t
group by t.id
```

The query don't execute and the error is: The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 't'.
I want to merge all rows with similar id into one row and different columns.
can anybody help me and solve the error?

Comment: Remove the `-` from the column aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues with the query.  This specific issue is that `id` is in both `table1` and `table2`.  So, just select the columns that you need in the outer query.

Also, `-` is not allowed for column aliases.  And the correct function name is `row_number()`, not `row-number()`:

```
select t.id,
      max(case when seq=1 then label end) as label_1,
      max(case when seq=2 then label end) as label_2,
      max(case when seq=3 then label end) as label_3,
      max(case when seq=4 then label end) as label_4,
      max(case when seq=5 then label end) as label_5,
from (select t1.id, t2.label,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t2.label) as seq
      from table1 t1 inner join 
           table2 t2
           on t1.id = t2.sequence
      ) t
group by t.id
```